# setting up reverse proxy nginx with Radarr - lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, proxy, nginx

I am facing an error 403 Forbidden when I try to access Radarr.

Here is my block setup for nginx in the site-available folder:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name radarr.mydomian www.radarr.mydomian;

location / {
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_pass             http://192.168.1.12:7878;   
proxy_read_timeout   90;
proxy_redirect        http://192.168.1.12:7878 http://radarr.mydomian;
}
}
```